# How to count the number of consecutive rows where only 2 columns have 0 as a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
  A B C
0 0 4 1
1 0 0 2
2 0 0 1
3 2 0 3
4 1 1 1
```

I need to count the number of consecutive rows where both A and B columns have 0 as a value.
If the counter is less than 10 or more than 20 I need to delete all of them.

In the example above the counter is 2, so I'm expecting this as an output:

```
  A B C
0 0 4 1
3 2 0 3
4 1 1 1
```

I tried this:

```
m1 = (df['A'].eq(0) & df['B'].eq(0)) 
m2 = df.groupby(m1.ne(m1.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').le(9) 
out = df[~(m1&m2)] 
return out
```

But it does nothing.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please update your question with the code attempt. Don't put it in a comment, that doesn't help.

Comment: Are all values in the columns A and B guaranteed to be 0 or positive? That is, are there no negative numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are all 0 or positive.

Comment: Then you could make the first part a bit easier, by adding columns A and B and checking if the result equals 0. But that's just what you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to set up the threshold condition on consecutive rows:

```
# boundaries below/above which
# to drop the rows (exclusive)
LOW, HIGH = 1, 2

# rows for which both A and B are 0
m = df[['A', 'B']].eq(0).all(axis=1)

# count the consecutive
count = m.groupby((m != m.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')

# keep only the values with non zero
# or with > LOW / < HIGH consecutive zeros
out = df.loc[(~m|count.between(LOW, HIGH, inclusive='neither'))]
```

Output:

```
  A B C
0 0 4 1
3 2 0 3
4 1 1 1
```